# Lighttpd closes connection when system time is changed

Tags: websocket, lighttpd

These are some of the parameters of my lighttpd config file.

```
server.modules += ( "mod_wstunnel", "mod_auth")
wstunnel.debug = 4
wstunnel.server.max-read-idle = 86400
#wstunnel.ping-interval = 5
#wstunnel.timeout = 30
```

When I open my web application, connection is created properly using websocket and connects to my c++ server.

All functionalities work except one.

One requirement of my application is to change the system time of machine, but when system time is changed, connection is closed and in log file it shows as :

```
`2019-02-12 14:04:10: (gw_backend.c.308) released proc: pid: 0 socket: tcp:127.0.0.1:10002 load: 0`
```

I want to maintain the connection even if system time is changed.

What other parameters can be used or any modification is required in these parameters?

**System OS : Fedora 26**

**Lighttpd version : 1.4.49**

Answer (score 0):

wstunnel.server.max-read-idle does not exist.  Did you test the lighttpd config before running it and look at the error trace?  It should have noted wstunnel.server.max-read-idle as an unrecognized directive.

The directives you seek are:

```
server.max-read-idle
server.max-write-idle
server.max-keep-alive-idle
```

However, if the time on your *server* (running lighttpd) is jumping more than a few seconds, then I suggest that is your primary problem.

Also, Fedora 26 reach end-of-life on May 29, 2018.  Supported Fedora have newer version of lighttpd.  The current version of lighttpd is lighttpd 1.4.53.

Comment: Hello @gstrauss , I have also tried by server.max-read-idle = 86400. But still no luck. Also you said "Fedora 26 reach end-of-life on May 29, 2018. Supported Fedora have newer version of lighttpd. The current version of lighttpd is lighttpd 1.4.53." Could it be the reason for this behavior? My requirement is to use Fedora 26. Should I use newer version of lighttpd?

Comment: There have been nearly 300 commits to lighttpd between 1.4.48 and 1.4.53, and you should use lighttpd 1.4.53 since it contains some security improvements that 1.4.48 does not have.  However, as I said above, if the time on your server (running lighttpd) is jumping more than a few seconds, then I suggest that is your primary problem.  If you can't fix the time, have you considered making your app more resilient and having it re-establish the websocket if the connection breaks?